# How to get Role Based on the email and password

Tags: c#

Please Help me How can i get Role when my UserName & password match.
I Have Below Data 
**LoginCredentialTab**

```
Id   UserName Psw   Role
1    ADAM      123   Admin
2    John      456    Hr
```

In My Repo Class I writen as

```
public bool Login(LoginCrediential Login)
        {
            var x = (from n in db.LoginCrediential
                    where n.UserName == Login.UserName && n.Password == Login.Password select n).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)return true;
            else return false;  //Here How can i get Roles When UserName & Psw Match
```

Comment: `x.Role` .....?

Comment: @David  wat is x.Role? can u please Explain

Comment: What have you tried to retrieve it? Generally you would select it similarly as you have excluded rows based on the UserName and Password. Your syntax is a bit odd, but standard sql would be along the lines of `select Role from db.LoginCredential where UserName == Login.UserName and Password == Login.Password`

Comment: @MDmohi: You have a variable called `x`.  Based on the information you've provided, I would expect `Role` to be a property on that variable.  Is it not?  What's the actual problem here?  What attempt have you made or what debugging have you done?

Comment: @scrappedcola  Here i need 2 fetch my Roles Based on my name & psw 4r that i can provide my Authorization Role in MVC

Comment: @David if both r match i wana 2 fetch its Role Thats it

Comment: @MDmohi: And you have a variable called `x` which contains the record.  That's it.  Have you *bothered to look at it*?

Comment: You are selecting the entire row which is an object with keys Id, UserName, Psw, and Role, what David is saying you have the row so you get the Role by `x.Role`. My suggestion is to just select the Role column and return that rather than the entire row. Either way you need to state what you have tried to solve this. Have you inspected `x` in the debugger to see what you have gotten back? Are there errors either runtime or compile time? In your Linq syntax selecting the column would be `select n.Role`

Comment: @David ,Scrappedcola Thank u soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the role after you return a value.

```
   public bool Login(LoginCrediential Login)
            {
                var x = (from n in db.LoginCrediential
                        where n.UserName == Login.UserName && n.Password == Login.Password select n).FirstOrDefault();
                if (x != null){
                  var roleOfTheUser = x.Role;
                  return true;}
                else return false;
```